# Draw polygon from sdo.geometry with OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, openlayers, oracle-spatial

I have some polygons in my oracle database, the column type is sdo.geometry, and I want to draw the polygon using OpenLayers.

The problem is OpenLayers reads WKT type and I can't convert to this type, because my version of Oracle is **"Oracle express Edition"**, and function like: `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(geometry)` or `geometry.get_WKT()` returns "(null)"

[image].

I already have something on my database cuss:
[image]

I'm using C#, and I haven't found any library for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a pure PLSQL WKT library you are welcome to take here
https://github.com/pauldzy/DZ_WKT

It **should** work with XE as there is no java nor any requirements beyond PLSQL.  Feel free to drop me a line or add an issue if you have additional questions.

WKT is not the most web-friendly format, you may wish to just use GeoJSON and I have another pure PLSQL library for that here
https://github.com/pauldzy/DZ_JSON

Note my GeoJSON code is for GeoJSON output only.  There is no input support as I assume folks will use native 12c JSON handling for that.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: To install just execute "dz_json_deploy.sql" ?

Comment: yep.  all resources have a "DZ" prefix so as to not conflict with your namespaces.  If for some reason you are using DZ as resource prefix I may have to fight you for it.  :)